# How to create new mysql user/db in Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql, administrator

Can any one please let me know how to create new user and new db in MySQL? How to use mysqladmin in Mac OS X?

Comment: Would you consider editing this question to make it more relevant to Mac OS X? General beginner mysql questions might get better answers at Stack Overflow. Also do read the FAQ so you are less likely to ask questions that read like "what book can I study to learn mysql on mac?" Cheers and welcome nevertheless!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the terminal client, generally you can do things like reset the root users password for mysql or create databases.

To create a new MySQL user:

- Login to MySQL in Terminal:`mysql -u username`
- In the prompt:`CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';`
- If you want to create a database: `create database name;` is all you need to do

If you do decide to use mysqladmin, [mysqladmin can create and drop databases, but it cannot create new users](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html).

Comment: The first link is broken

Comment: Apologies but it looks like that's going to be permanent, they no longer appear to have a selfsame site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a GUI client, like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/).

Comment: This is a bad answer - you should at least tell people how to do it with the program you're suggesting

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. I used the below commands to figure it out.

```
Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:bin sarbbottam$ mysql -u root
mysql> create database tutorialdb;
mysql> create user 'tutorialuser'@'localhost' identified by 'tutorialuser';
mysql> grant all on tutorialdb.* to 'tutorialuser'@'localhost';
mysql> exit
Bye

Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:bin sarbbottam$ mysql -u tutorialuser -p
Enter password: 

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1532
Server version: 5.5.9 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many choices, you can use [MySQL Query browser](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) , or [PhpMyadmin](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8179/phpmyadmin).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try, introduce complete path to mysql:

Go to Terminal:

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u user
```

I hope help you!

Comment: On a vanilla system this will lead to `-bash: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: No such file or directory-bash: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqlx: No such file or directory`

Comment: this is on MAC.

Comment: Yes. On a standard OS X installation, there is no `mysql` in `/usr/local`.

Comment: Please It's work for me. Check this https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/

Comment: I'm sure it does, *after* a manual installation of MySQL (which is the part missing in your answer)